# Why does this DFS-based topological sort algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort

Here is the algorithm that I pulled from [this competitive programming resource](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/topological-sort.html).

```
int n; // number of vertices
vector<vector<int>> adj; // adjacency list of graph
vector<bool> visited;
vector<int> ans;

void dfs(int v) {
    visited[v] = true;
    for (int u : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[u])
            dfs(u);
    }
    ans.push_back(v);
}

void topological_sort() {
    visited.assign(n, false);
    ans.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (!visited[i])
            dfs(i);
    }
    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
}
```

How does this algorithm avoid adding vertices to the topologically sorted collection that have incoming directed edges? Say, for example, that the first vertex (0 in this example) checked by the for loop has an incoming directed edge from vertex (1). What is stopping this algorithm from outputting (0) before first ensuring that (1) has been output?

Comment: do you understand recursion? if you do, try depicting the recursion tree for the program, you will get your answer and if you don't try to understand recursion first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's building the output vector backwards.  If there's an incoming directed edge from vertex (1) to vertex (0), you *want* to output (0) before (1).

Note that `dfs(int v)` calls `ans.push_back(v)` only after it recurses to all its descendants.  This ensures that anything that follows `v` will have been added to the output vector before `v`.  Anything not `visited[]` after `dfs(0)` returns is either unrelated to `0` or its descendants (and therefore can be added later), or precedes them (and therefore should be added later).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the DFS approach requires the graph to not have any cycles. If the graph **does** have cycles, the DFS will not detect it and will give a wrong result. If the graph **does not** have cycles, the DFS will work. Certain other algorithms than DFS for finding the topological sort can detect cycles and rightly give an error if any cycle exists, since a topological sort is not possible for a graph with cycles. So, it is a very good question you ask.